# target .class:after:hover in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to target this :after in jQuery:

```
.a1 {
  position: relative;
}

.a1:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 3px;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 5px;
  right: 0;
  background: #3f92c3;
  transition: width .4s linear;
  -webkit-transition: width .4s linear;
}

.a1:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  background: #3f92c3;
}
```

The scroll code looks like this (example):

```
$(function() {
  var header = $("#header");
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scroll >= 100) {
      header.addClass("scrolled");
    } else {}
  });
});
```

HTML:

```
<li><a class="a1" href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
<li><a class="a1" href="#">Services</a></li>
<li><a class="a1" href="#">Contact</a></li>
```

I found this out after searching alot and it worked byt i don't know how the underline can keep the hover color after i mouseleave .a1 :

```
$('#menuwrapper').mouseenter(function() {
  if ($('#pseudo').length) {
    $('#pseudo').remove();
  } else {
    var css = '<style id="pseudo">.a1::after{background: red !important;}</style>';
    document.head.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', css);
  };
});
```

I tried mouseleave but it didn't work.

So i just want that if i scroll (that i know how it works) that the underline under the menu .a1 stay's black , because if i leave the underline hover it goes back to

```
.a1:after {
  background: #3f92c3;
}
```

I want it to stay black.

Comment: There is no jQuery selector for `:after` or `:before` You need to control it via a class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selecting and manipulating CSS pseudo-elements such as ::before and ::after using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/selecting-and-manipulating-css-pseudo-elements-such-as-before-and-after-usin)

Comment: Can't seem to make it work

Comment: Some basic understanding of CSS might help.

Comment: Can you explain that answer. Your saying that it can be fixed with css?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pseudo elements like `:before` and `:after` are not the part of DOM because they are not real elements as called **pseudo**...so you can't target them using `jQuery`

As you are adding class `scrolled` on scroll, so better to use this class in css like

```
.scrolled .a1:after{
  background: black;
}
```

```js
$(function() {
  var header = $("#header");
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scroll >= 100) {
      header.addClass("scrolled");
    } else {
      header.removeClass("scrolled");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin-top: 150px;
  font: 13px Verdana;
  height: 500px
}

#header {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
}

#header li {
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.a1 {
  position: relative;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.a1:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 3px;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 5px;
  right: 0;
  background: #3f92c3;
  transition: width .4s linear;
  -webkit-transition: width .4s linear;
}

.a1:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
}

.scrolled .a1:after {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="header">
  <li><a class="a1" href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
  <li><a class="a1" href="#">Services</a></li>
  <li><a class="a1" href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @user9356960 you have to share your full code so that I can solve the issue

Comment: Incredible that i have to search for hours only for a underline color

Comment: I updated my question, i found out how to change the underline color with some code i found but i don't know how the color can stay black if i leave the underline hover again. So maybe we need to remove that after background and make it black as the header is scrolled. Can you help me with this? Then i am going to work further on my website now. I hope i will hear from you, i am really going crazy about this.......

Comment: @user9356960 see it happen sometimes..:)..the main thing you have to go to the right direction to solve the problem otherwise it can take a whole life to solve...BTW I updated my answer and also no need to add background on hover..just add it to `.a1:after`

Comment: Thank you so much for your time, really appreciate it. Have a good day!

Answer (score 0):

try to use jQuery hover method, but also you cant touch :after :before elements from jQuery

```
$("p").hover(function(){
$(this).css("background-color", "yellow");
}, function(){
$(this).css("background-color", "pink");});
```

Comment: Nothing works can you make a code for me using this.